# qmake and Qt installation root directory

Tags: qt, configuration-files, qmake

How could I refer to Qt installation root directory available in shell as `qmake -v`. Is there a special qmake variable or a way to store the outcome of `qmake -v` in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation [Configuring qmake](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-environment-reference.html) hints about the existence of several configuration variables of type `QT_INSTALL_XXX.` The right variable that specifies the root location of Qt installation is `QT_INSTALL_PREFIX`. The proper way to access this form qmake file is `$$[QT_INSTALL_PREFIX]`.